# Select aleatory row from table for each row of the select

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
    R.ArrivalAirportID, 
    (
        SELECT TOP(1) A1.AirportID 
        FROM Airport A1 
        WHERE A1.ISO_country = 'PT' 
        ORDER BY( NEWID())
    ) 'PT Aleatory Airport'
FROM Routes R WHERE (
    SELECT A2.ISO_country 
    FROM Airports A2 
    WHERE A2.AirportID = R.ArrivalAirportID
) != 'PT
```

This is my SELECT and I want random `AirportID`s in column `PT Aleatory Airport` but the `AirportID` is always the same for all rows of SELECT.

How can I have a random `AirportID FROM Airport A1 WHERE A1.ISO_country = 'PT'` for each `R.ArrivalAirportID` in the SELECT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an outer reference in your subquery to ensure it is executed on a row by row basis, not just once. I think this would probably do it:

```
SELECT 
    R.ArrivalAirportID, 
    (
        SELECT TOP(1) A1.AirportID 
        FROM Airport A1 
        WHERE A1.ISO_country = 'PT' 
        AND AI.AirportID <> R.ArrivalAirportID
        ORDER BY( NEWID())
    ) 'PT Aleatory Airport'
FROM Routes R WHERE (
    SELECT A2.ISO_country 
    FROM Airports A2 
    WHERE A2.AirportID = R.ArrivalAirportID
) != 'PT';
```

Since `R.ArrivalAirportID` is restricted to airports where the country code is not `PT`, and `AI.AirportID` is restricted to airports where the country code is `PT`, the two IDs could never be equal anyway, so this additional predicate does not change the meaning of the query, but does change the execution plan.

If this does not work, then an alternative is to allocate a sequential row number to each airport in the aleatory pot, then for each

```
WITH RandomAirports AS
(   
    SELECT  a.AirportID,
            RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.AirportID)
    FROM    Airport AS a 
    WHERE   a.ISO_country = 'PT' 
)
SELECT  r.ArrivalAirportID,
        [PT Aleatory Airport] = ra.AirportID
FROM    Routes AS r
        INNER JOIN dbo.Airports AS a
            ON a.AirportID = r.ArrivalAirportID
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RandomAirports) AS rm (RandomMax)
        LEFT JOIN RandomAirports AS ra
            ON r1.RowNumber = CEILING(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * rm.RandomMax)
WHERE   a.ISO_country <> 'PT';
```

The key line here is:

```
r1.RowNumber = CEILING(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * rm.RandomMax)
```

This generates a random number between 1 and however many airports there are to choose from, so will effectively pick one at random.

Comment: I saw your comment, the first works for me! Thank you!